# Responsive round image links with hover effect

Tags: jquery, image, hover, geometry

I need to have multiple-circle-shaped-clickable-responsive images on a website.

**I can :**

- use HTML/JS/Jquery/Bootstrap/CSS to achieve this

**The images :**

- are round with blank/transparent corners
- change to another similar image when hovered by the mouse, and change back when the mouse leave
- are more than one on the page
- let me go somewhere else when i click on them
- should be responsive, and so should the effects listed above

I've been trying by myself all day long but i still have issues; here's my code :

https://jsfiddle.net/83t58rbm/2 (**JsFiddle**)

Since i don't have any reputation on the website, here's a botched URL, so is the code below, please refer to the JsFiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/83t58rbm/2/embedded/result (**Fullscreen**)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("area[title='area_enfance']").mouseover(function() {
    $('img[name=enfance]').attr('src', $('img[name=enfance]').attr('data-active'));
  });
  $("area[title='area_intimite']").mouseover(function() {
    $('img[name=intimite]').attr('src', $('img[name=intimite]').attr('data-active'));
  });
  $("area[title='area_enfance']").mouseout(function() {
    $('img[name=enfance]').attr('src', $('img[name=enfance]').attr('data-inactive'));
  });
  $("area[title='area_intimite']").mouseout(function() {
    $('img[name=intimite]').attr('src', $('img[name=intimite]').attr('data-inactive'));
  });
});
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <map name="m_intimite">
        <area shape="circle" coords="272,272,272" href="someurl" title="area_intimite">
      </map>
      <img name="intimite" usemap="#m_intimite" src="original-img" class="img-responsive" data-active="new-img" data-inactive="original-img" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <map name="m_enfance">
        <area shape="circle" coords="272,272,272" href="otherurl" title="area_enfance">
      </map>
      <img name="enfance" usemap="#m_enfance" src="original-img" class="img-responsive" data-active="new-img" data-inactive="original-img" />
    </div>
  </div>
  </script>

  </html>
```

**The main problem :**

If you reduce the width of the fullscreen result as much as you can on your computer browser, the image will reduce a little, as expected (maybe it should be able to reduce some more (?)), but of course, the radius of circle  (which has an mouseover/mouseout jquery effect and an url to go to) will not reduce, since it is set to 272,272,272 coordinates, therefore allowing any user to point their mouse in the blank area, and still have the mouseover effect and the href active.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BJfC.jpg (**Screenshot**)

As you can see in a screenshot, the blue circle represents the circle , which desynchronized from the top image, because i reduced the browser width as much as i could after the page loaded.

Any help would be appreciated, Sorry for the awfully bad formatted post.

Much love.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can simplify quite a bit. Give this a try.

```
.circle {
    border-radius: 100%;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.circle a {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
}

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="circle">
                <a href="#" data-active="http://placehold.it/600x600/ff0000/ffffff" data-inactive="http://placehold.it/600x600"></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="circle">
                <a href="#" data-active="http://placehold.it/600x600" data-inactive="http://placehold.it/600x600/ff0000/ffffff"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.circle a').each(function () {
        var activeImg = $(this).data('active'),
            inactiveImg = $(this).data('inactive');

        $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + inactiveImg + ')')
        .mouseover(function () {
            $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + activeImg + ')')
        })
        .mouseout(function () {
            $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + inactiveImg + ')');
        });
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/83t58rbm/10/)**

Comment: Wow, such skill, I will enjoy my Week-End while trying to understand all your funny-to-me-yet-working CSS. Thank you very very much. I don't have enough reputation to put an upvote on your answer, sorry about that !

Michel.